# Regex to match pattern domain\username

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex for the below pattern, but I'm doing in an incorrect way. Can you please help me? Basically the pattern is like domain\username. Domain should accept alphanumeric plus - as special character, username should only have alphanumeric characters. There should be \ after domain pattern. The regex should be in JavaScript, using String.match() method.

Example:

```
Desktop-123\john123
Desktop123\john1
Desktop123\john
Desktop-123\john
```

Regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\[a-zA-Z0-9]$/
```

Comment: @srivastavab please also add output you are expecting and you are getting

Comment: Ok I did a mistake, I need to include two \ and + at end to allow one or more characters.  /^[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain name can not consist of only `-`, you can first match 1+ alpha numberic chars and optionally repeat a `-` followed by 1+ alpha numeric chars.

**Note** to repeat the character class 1 or more times or else you would match a single char.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed in the character class
- `(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat a `-` and any of the listed in the character class
- `\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match a `\` and again match 1+ times any of the listed in the character class
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UpLV05/1)